How to render content from the acf fields in wordpress correctly?
I'm trying to play around building custom themes for wordpress and I am using ACF to add content to a page. But when i use the functions to render the content it comes out like this <p>sdfnvsdbnfgvsdvbnsv</p> and the code i used for this was <p>sdfnvsdbnfgvsdvbnsv</p>.
I played around with and finally got to render it correctly by changing the code a bit.
function get_clean_acf_field($field_name)
{
    $raw_content = get_field($field_name);
    return esc_html(wp_strip_all_tags($raw_content)); // Sanitize and strip tags
}

?>

But now i'm wondering did i really need to do all of this just to get it rendered correctly? It seems weird to me that i have to use a html strip tags function to do this. So i want to know if i did it the correct way and if there are any other better solutions out there.
